# How to create a repeatable / reusable divs in the metabox?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, javascript

I have a meta box:

```
<?php
function custom_meta_box_markup() { 
    global $post;
    $meta_box_text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text', true );
    $meta_box_text_day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text-day', true );
    ?>
        <div class="schedule-wrapper" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5; padding-bottom: 5px;">
            <div><input name="meta-box-text-day" type="text" placeholder="Day" value="<?php if ($meta_box_text_day) { echo $meta_box_text_day; }?>"></div>
            <div><input name="meta-box-text" type="text" placeholder="Time" value="<?php if ($meta_box_text) { echo $meta_box_text; }?>"></div>           
        </div>
        <button name ="add-more" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;"> Add More.. </button>
<?php }

function add_custom_meta_box()
{
    $id             = 'demo-meta-box';
    $title          = 'Schedule';
    $callback       = 'custom_meta_box_markup';
    $screen         = 'dramas';
    $context        = 'side';
    $priority       = 'high';
    $callback_args  = 'null';
    add_meta_box($id, $title, $callback, $screen, $context, $priority, $callback_args);
}
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");
```

I save the meta box like this:

```
function save_custom_meta_box($post_id)
{
    global $post;   
    //skip auto save
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    //check for DRAMAS post type only
    if( $post->post_type == "dramas" ) {
        if( isset($_POST['meta-box-text']) ) { update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text', $_POST['meta-box-text'] );}
        if( isset($_POST['meta-box-text-day']) ) { update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text-day', $_POST['meta-box-text-day'] );}
    }
}

add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);
```

The out put of the code in admin panel looks like this and it works fine. It saves the values and displays.

**By default** when we visit to the admin panel:

[image: BEFORE SAVE]

**After save** a value:

[image: AFTER SAVE]

Everything works fine in saving and displaying values.

Now I want to add more of `schedule-wrapper` divs one below another with it's inside contents when the button `add-more` is clicked.

How can I do that.?

and how to get those value in the front end?